# Not using Where statement in a context

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Goal:**

If you have the input data that is `-10` then you should not use the `WHERE` statement in function.

**Problem:**

I do not know how to solve it in this context. You have to use `WHERE` and `not WHERE` depending on what input data you retrieve

**Info:**

If you use `-10` as a input data then you should retrieve all data based on `[dbo].[testing]` and it is okay to retrieve data that is `null` in `[dbo].[testing2]` in relation to `LEFT JOIN`.

*The code and its data is a sample from production phase.

Thank you!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testing](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [value] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [category] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testing2](
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [value] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [category] [int] NULL,
    [test_id] [int] NULL,
    [id_type] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.testt ( 
    @data int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT 
        a.[id],
        a.[value],
        a.[category],
        b.[id_type]
    FROM [dbo].[testing] a left join [dbo].[testing2] b on a.id = b.[id]
    where b.[id_type] = @data
)

INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[testing] VALUES 
(1, '', 2), (2, '', 3), (3, 'a', 2), (4, 'a', 2),
(5, 'b', 2), (6, 'b', 2), (7, 'c', 2), (8, 'c', 2),
(9, 'c', 2), (10, 'c', 2);


INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[testing2] VALUES 
(3, 'a' ,2 ,11 ,1), (4, 'a' ,2 ,11 ,1),
(5, 'a' ,2 ,11 ,0), (6, 'a' ,2 ,11 ,2);

select
    s.[id],
    s.[value],
    s.[category],
    s.[id_type]
from dbo.testt(1) s
```

Comment: Regardless the where b.anything  turns the left join to an inner join.  Question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `where b.[id_type] = @data OR @data = -10` in the `testt` function ?

So your function would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.testt ( 
    @data int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT 
        a.[id],
        a.[value],
        a.[category],
        b.[id_type]
    FROM [dbo].[testing] a 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[testing2] b on a.id = b.[id]
    WHERE b.[id_type] = @data OR @data = -10
)
```

Comment: Not the same as not using a where as it still changes the left join to an inner join

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have your WHERE clause check if @data is either -10 or matches b.[id_type].

```
WHERE (@data = -10) OR (b.[id_type] = @data)
```

Comment: Not the same as not using a where as it still changes the left join to an inner join

Comment: If @data is -10 then the b check is ignored.  It does not make it into an inner join.

Comment: I will have to test that out but I will take your word for now

Comment: Thank you for your help!